# What does this AttributeError means ? 'int' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a problem with my function "draw_pieces()" because when i run my code, i have the following errors: (Without "draw_pieces()" my code works)

```
_cnfmerge: fallback due to: 'int' object is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thierry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 102, in _cnfmerge
    cnf.update(c)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thierry\Desktop\Chess\Chessboard.py", line 31, in <module>
    draw_pieces()
  File "C:\Users\Thierry\Desktop\Chess\Chessboard.py", line 28, in draw_pieces
    canvas.create_image=Canvas(30,30, image=photo, anchor=CENTER, state=NORMAL)
  File "C:\Users\Thierry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2244, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'canvas', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Thierry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2129, in __init__
    cnf = _cnfmerge((cnf, kw))
  File "C:\Users\Thierry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 105, in _cnfmerge
    for k, v in c.items():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("512x512")

rows = 8
columns = 8
color1 = "#b35821" #Flery Orange
color2 = "#efcb9d" #New Tan
dim_square = 64

canvas=Canvas(root, width=512, height=512)
canvas.pack()

photo=PhotoImage(file="blackk.gif")

def draw_chessboard():
    color = color2
    for r in range(rows):
        color = color1 if color == color2 else color2
        for c in range(columns):
            x1 = (c * dim_square)
            y1 = ((7-r) * dim_square)
            x2 = x1 + dim_square
            y2 = y1 + dim_square
            canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color, tags="area")
            color = color1 if color == color2 else color2

def draw_pieces():
    canvas.create_image=Canvas(30,30, image=photo, anchor=CENTER, state=NORMAL)

draw_chessboard()
draw_pieces()

root.mainloop()
```

Can you help me to fix this ?
Thanks in advance for your help :).

Comment: Please show the code where the error occurs!  You probably have an `int` where you think you have a dictionary.  Please show the complete traceback, not edited highlights.

Comment: You should copy and paste the entire traceback (indented by 4 spaces) into your question. Regardless, `create_image` is the name of a `Canvas` widget _method_, so it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish by replacing it with another (`Canvas`) object.

Comment: I just want to place pieces on my board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried making this change, and the program ran without error:

**original**

```
canvas.create_image=Canvas(30,30, image=photo, anchor=CENTER, state=NORMAL)
```

**change to:**

```
canvas.create_image(30,30, image=photo, anchor=CENTER, state=NORMAL)
```

I also have this resource that I like to go to when I'm using tkinter.  I hope this helps.

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf

Comment: Thanks, tkinter isn't very intuitive for me ^^